# Python lists, change the value of matching items with matching index

Tags: python, list, indexing, match

If I have

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 6]
list2 = [4, 3, 5, 6]
```

how can I change the values of anything that matches between the two list? Only if the Index also matches

the desired output is

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 'match']
```

I was using this

```
for idx,x in enumerate(list1):
    if x in list2:  
        list1[idx] = 'match'
```

But this replaces the 3 and the 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative way of achieving the same outcome:

```
list1 = ['match' if v == list2[k] else v for (k, v) in enumerate(list1)]
```

Comment: This is actually not the best answer, at all.

Comment: Probably not, but it is faster than your answer by approximately 5%. However, the zip method is even faster.

Answer (score 2):

Use `zip` to iterate both lists simultaneously and check each value vs each other instead of using `in`:

```
list3 = ['match' if x == y else x for x, y in zip(list1, list2)]
```

In regular form this is:

```
list3 = []
for x, y in zip(list1, list2):
    if x == y:
        list3.append(x)
    else:
        list3.append('match')
```

Comment: neither of these gave me the desired output [1, 2, 3, match]

Comment: Are you sure you aren't looking at list3 and not list1? It makes no sense to edit list1 as that's your input data.

Comment: If you really want to edit list1 just replace list3 with list1 and remove the first line in the second example.

Answer (score 0):

If you zip both lists together, you can compare their items - if you want to preserve the original list and potentially write less confusing code than list comprehension, you could do the following:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 6]
list2 = [4, 3, 5, 6]

for i, t in enumerate(zip(list1, list2)):
    a, b = t  # unpack the tuple t
    if a == b:
       list1[i]="match"
```

At the end, `list1` is `[1, 2, 3, 'match']`.

Answer (score 0):

```
list(map(lambda a, b: a if a != b else 'match', list1, list2))
```

```
[1, 2, 3, 'match']
```